# What web technology is used to send twitter notifications on the front end like in this video?

Tags: web, twitter, push-notification, notifications

had a question.
i have 2 web browsers open with twitter (2 different accounts)
on the left browser, i liked  a tweet.
You can see on the right browser, i almost instantly got the notification.
What web technology (in the video below) is used on the front end (or is it back end?) to do this considering this isnt iOS/Android?

[image: video]

Comment: Web sockets and / or long polling. Inspect the network tab of your browser.

Comment: ok. let me look up long polling.  thanks